# Is there syntax that will permit window communication in realbasic/xojo?

Tags: realbasic, xojo

I am creating a project which requires me to have cross window interaction.

More specifically, for the text from a textbox object to be stored as a variable on another window.

Is this possible in Xojo/ Realbasic and what is its syntax?

[Visual, using shapes to represent objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsS4n.png)

Comment: You can refer to public properties and controls of other windows by using the `WindowName.ControlName.PropertyName` or `WindowName.PropertyName` syntax.

Comment: Thank you so much, that is exactly what I needed! I am creating a hangman project for school that requires this exact syntax to get everything working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion it would be better to add a Module to your project that contains all the global properties. Than you can access these properties from all your windows like mySettings.myProperty1 without being bound to the window name. Or you can add them to App as global property.

Then just add a line to the editfields change event that transfers the text to the new global property like mySettings.myProperty1 = Me.Text

This would allow to change your window name or add multiple windows without requiring a change to your properties. And it will protect your editfield against changes (by mistake) from other windows.